# How could I make a notification off of information from a DatePicker/TimePicker

Tags: java, android, push-notification, android-datepicker, android-timepicker

I am making a time management application. What I am trying to do is have some information:

- DatePicker=to select the date of an event
- TimePicker=to select the time of an event
- Couple EditTexts=to put in information about the event(length in minutes, title)

So I have all of this in an activity, and now I need to find a way that I can take all of this information and make it into a push notification which will notify me at the date selected and at the time selected and for the amount of time inputted. Please tell if this is possible. If it is not, then please tell me if I can find some other way to do something similar.
Here is my .java:

```
package net.mastersofdisasters2.timagement;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;


public class assignment extends Activity implements DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener

{

private TimePicker timePicker1;


private int hour;
private int minute;

static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 999;


// display current time
public void setCurrentTimeOnView() {


    timePicker1 = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timeofassignment);
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);



    // set current time into timepicker
    timePicker1.setCurrentHour(hour);
    timePicker1.setCurrentMinute(minute);

}






@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
            // set time picker as current time
            return new TimePickerDialog(this,
                    timePickerListener, hour, minute,false);

    }
    return null;
}

private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timePickerListener =
        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int selectedHour,
                                  int selectedMinute) {
                hour = selectedHour;
                minute = selectedMinute;



                // set current time into timepicker
                timePicker1.setCurrentHour(hour);
                timePicker1.setCurrentMinute(minute);

            }
        };

private static String pad(int c) {
    if (c >= 10)
        return String.valueOf(c);
    else
        return "0" + String.valueOf(c);
}

DatePicker dp=null;
Calendar cal=null;
TextView mcdate=null;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_assignment);
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.create_assignment);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(assignment.this,PushNotification.class));
        }
    });
enter code here
    setCurrentTimeOnView();`enter code here`
    dp=(DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.dateofassignment);
    mcdate=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.enter_assignment_datetime);
    cal=Calendar.getInstance();
    dp.init(dp.getYear(),dp.getMonth(),dp.getDayOfMonth(),this);



}
public void onDateChanged(DatePicker dpview, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    cal.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
    java.util.Date d = cal.getTime();
    mcdate.setText(String.valueOf(d.getMonth() +1) + "/" + String.valueOf(d.getDate()) + "/" + String.valueOf((d.getYear() + 1900)));
}



}
```

Now that was just to add the DatePicker and TimePickers. Now what do I do to create a push notification from the inputted information?
Heres my activity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/light_blue"
>
<TextView android:id="@+id/enter_assigment_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="@bool/abc_action_bar_embed_tabs"
    android:text="@string/assignmentadd"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="@color/light_black"
    />
<EditText android:id="@+id/enter_assignment_field"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/assignmentadd"
    android:layout_below="@id/enter_assigment_text"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/enter_assignment_datetime"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/assignment_datetime"
    android:layout_below="@+id/enter_assignment_field"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="@color/light_black"/>
<DatePicker
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/enter_assignment_field"
    android:id="@+id/dateofassignment"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp">
    </DatePicker>
<TextView android:id="@+id/date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dateofassignment"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/thechosendate"
    />
<TimePicker
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/timeofassignment"
    android:layout_below="@+id/date"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
    </TimePicker>
<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/choose_assignment_length"
    android:layout_below="@+id/timeofassignment"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/length_of_assignment">
    </TextView>
<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/enter_assignment_length"
    android:hint="@string/length_of_assignment"
    android:layout_below="@+id/choose_assignment_length"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
<Button android:id="@+id/create_assignment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/enter_assignment_length"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/submit"
    android:background="@color/cornflower_blue"
    />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Please Help quickly I need to finish this very soon

Comment: you can use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

Comment: Yes you can create an Alarm to serve your purpose.

Comment: Yes I know but the question that I am asking is how can I use the AlarmManager to get the information entered by the user. Tutorials would be nice.